# Sorting Numerical String Values of List based on two columns Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains two columns named as TimeCount and FRAME.
I want to sort the two columns based on TimeCount first, then FRAME.

I used sort() function to sort the list and it works correctly other than it captures 10 as 1 because the column contains String numerical values.

```
# Find common parts
intersection = list(set(csv_1) & set(csv_2) & set(csv_3))

# Sort the list
intersection.sort()
```

As you can see from the row number 11 to 13, the second column has 0, 10, 2 as sorted values.
I tried to use sort(key = int), but the first column prevents it because of ':' symbol.
I want to sort the second column correctly. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
data = [('11:14:02', '7'), ('11:14:02', '6'), ('11:14:06', '0'), ('11:14:06', '10'), ('11:14:06', '2')]
sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1])))
```

Output:​

```
[('11:14:02', '6'),
 ('11:14:02', '7'),
 ('11:14:06', '0'),
 ('11:14:06', '2'),
 ('11:14:06', '10')]
```

But do note that next time please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not an image

Comment: It gives me an value error like: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i'